# Push fails to GitHub "RPC Failed" and "remote end hung up unexpectedly"

Tags: git, github, curl

I am using Git out of PyCharm on Windows 10.

I am trying to push the initial commit to a >2Gb GitHub Repo.

Just before pushing to the private Repo, I get the following error message in the Event Log:

```
Push failed
RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Total 492 (delta 98), reused 0 (delta 0)
the remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

This Error occurs repeatedly even after changing the buffer size as advised [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/stashkb/git-push-fails-fatal-the-remote-end-hung-up-unexpectedly-282988530.html).

Detailed Error Log shortend with [...] when repetitive:

```
21:10:15.242: [reponame] git -c credential.helper= -c core.quotepath=false -c log.showSignature=false add --ignore-errors -A -f -- README.md
21:10:15.933: [reponame] git -c credential.helper= -c core.quotepath=false -c log.showSignature=false commit -F C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Temp\git-commit-msg-.txt --amend --
[master b8c325d] comittmesssage
 Date: Sun Dec 13 19:25:51 2020 +0100
 485 files changed, 49125 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 file.txt
 create mode 100644 file.exe
 create mode 100644 README.md
 create mode 100644 file.JPG
[...]
 create mode 100644 file.JPG
21:11:06.017: [reponame] git -c credential.helper= -c core.quotepath=false -c log.showSignature=false push --progress --porcelain origin refs/heads/master:master --set-upstream
Enumerating objects: 492, done.
Counting objects:   0% (1/492)
[...]
Counting objects: 100% (492/492)
Counting objects: 100% (492/492), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects:   0% (1/490)
[...]
Compressing objects: 100% (490/490)
Compressing objects: 100% (490/490), done.
Writing objects:   0% (1/492)
Writing objects:   1% (5/492)
[...]
Writing objects:  79% (393/492), 1.99 GiB | 1.10 MiB/s
Writing objects:  79% (393/492), 2.00 GiB | 1.13 MiB/s
error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Writing objects:  80% (394/492), 2.00 GiB | 1.14 MiB/s
[...]
Writing objects: 100% (492/492), 2.64 GiB | 25.77 MiB/s
Writing objects: 100% (492/492), 2.65 GiB | 1.44 MiB/s, done.
Total 492 (delta 98), reused 0 (delta 0)
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Done
22:00:20.158: [reponame] git -c credential.helper= -c core.quotepath=false -c log.showSignature=false push --progress --porcelain origin refs/heads/master:master --set-upstream
Enumerating objects: 492, done.
Counting objects:   0% (1/492)
[...]
Writing objects:  79% (393/492), 1.99 GiB | 1.04 MiB/s
error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Writing objects:  80% (394/492), 2.00 GiB | 1.04 MiB/s
[...]
Writing objects: 100% (492/492), 2.65 GiB | 1.40 MiB/s, done.
Total 492 (delta 98), reused 0 (delta 0)
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Done
```

I hope for Suggestions for my problem. Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean that pushing your first initial commit in this repo results in sending 2.65 Gb over to github ? What is the content of your repo ? pictures ?

Comment: Its a ML Dataset

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GitHub does not allow a push to exceed 2 GB.  If your repository contains multiple commits, you can push them incrementally, like so:

```
$ git rev-list --reverse HEAD | perl -ne 'print unless $i++ % 5;' | \
    xargs -I{} git push origin +{}:main
```

This will push every fifth commit, which is suitable if you have a very small repo you've just started.  For a longer, existing repo, 5000 is more appropriate.  You can then follow up with a normal push.

If your repository really contains more than 2 GB of objects in a single commit, you won't be able to push it to GitHub.  You should consider what in your repository is causing it to be so large and fix that.  For example, you should not check in any sort of binary dependencies or build products into a repository and should avoid checking in dependencies of any sort in general.

Also, in general, you shouldn't raise the `http.postBuffer` setting unless [you're on a network with a known broken proxy or otherwise know you need it](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#Documentation/gitfaq.txt-WhatdoescodehttppostBuffercodereallydo).  While the Bitbucket documentation describes a situation with such a broken proxy, it's better to fix that proxy because you will otherwise waste a very substantial amount of memory on most pushes.